# PHP/MySQL - Registration form issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problem with registration form using php script, i am checked alot of posts for this type of issues and i'm stil not getting it.. i'm trying to write codes by myself to insert user into database after guest is trying to register new user..

I wrote code like that and i know it's not suppose to be like that but i'm atleas trying by myself to learn something and if you guys can help me give your professional tips what should i add and what should i remove to make secure and working code

PHP Code i wrote

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");

if (!isset($_POST['registracija'])); {



    $uporabnik = $_POST['uporabnik']; #----------- Username ------------#
    $email = $_POST['email'];#----------- Email ------------#
    $geslo = $_POST['geslo'];#----------- Password ------------#
    $geslo2 = $_POST['geslo2'];#----------- Confirm password ------------#
    $spol = $_POST['spol']; #----------- Gender ------------#

if($geslo == $geslo2){ #----------- Password / password confirm ------------#
  $msg = 'gesli se ujemata'; #----------- Passwords are same ------------#
    } else {
        $msg = 'gesli se ne ujemata'; #----------- Error confirm password ------------#
    }

}


if (strcmp ($uporabnik, $email, $geslo, $geslo2, $spol) == 0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO uporabniki (uporabnik, email, geslo, spol)
VALUES ('$uporabnik', '$email', '$geslo', '$spol')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Registered Successfully!";
    }
}


?>
```

and here is html version of registration form

```
<form method="Post" >
      <?php if(isset($msg)) echo $msg;  ?><br>

         <label >Uporabniško ime</label>
         <input type="text" name="uporabnik"  placeholder="Username..." size="50" required/> 
         <br>
         <label >Email</label>
         <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Email" size="50" required/> 
         <br>
         <label>Spol</label>
      <input type="radio"  name="spol" value="moški" required> Moški
         <input type="radio"  name="spol" value="ženska" required> Ženska
         <br>
         <label>Geslo</label>
      <input type="password" name="geslo"  placeholder="Password..." size="50" required/>
         <br>
         <label >Ponovi geslo</label>
      <input type="password" name="geslo2" id="geslo2" placeholder="Confirm password..." size="50" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="registracija" id="registracija" value="Registracija">
    </form>
```

I hope you guys won't judge me and you'll help me out so i can learn more.. I'm new at this 
Thank you for your time and tips!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: You say there is an 'issue' in your title? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @JayBlanchard oh yeah im getting errors like this `Notice: Undefined index: uporabnik in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: geslo in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: geslo2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: spol in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 12

Warning: strcmp() expects exactly 2 parameters, 5 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 24
Registered Successfully! `

Comment: @JayBlanchard when im refresh the site it's automaticly insert into database new id user and im not insert anything into <input>

Comment: Change `<form method="Post" >` to `<form method="post" >`. Is your PHP in the same file as your HTML?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard i did and it's still inserting into database after refreshing the site. It is.

Comment: @JayBlanchard `Notice: Undefined index: uporabnik in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: geslo in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: geslo2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: spol in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14

Warning: strcmp() expects exactly 2 parameters, 5 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 25`

Comment: Your variables are not getting set.

Comment: @JayBlanchard so i have to add array befor variables or?

Comment: Add a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of the PHP before your `if` condition to make sure you're getting the variables after you click the submit button. Post the results here.